# Doubt on resistor circuit

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance

How are we able to flip the triangular resistor to the opposite breaking its connection with the lower 2r resistor?

[image]

Comment: There is no real question, what do you mean? Does the current remains constant? Does it open a door to a world in a different dimension, can you make your question **clear**?

Comment: @iharob click on the question to view the image.

Comment: I saw the image, it's of no help at all.

Comment: Perhaps you could add some more context to the question.

Comment: Questions here get closed if the *entire question* is not included. Instead of posting just a link, please put all information relevant to the question here so we can read it.

Comment: Hi satyatech. Welcome to Phys.SE. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: @DanielSank AFAIK people with minimal rep cannot post images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean, how do we know we can transform the circuit this way without changing any of the node voltages or branch currents?

Let's use your node "B" as the reference node, and assign it a potential of 0 V. Then we can see that $V_A$ is just the battery voltage.

From symmetry, we can tell that the voltage at "C" must be $\frac{V_A}{2}$.

Similarly, in the transformed circuit, symmetry tells us that the voltage at "C" will still be $\frac{V_A}{2}$, as will the voltage at the junction between the two "r"-valued resistors at the bottom of the schematic. Since this voltage doesn't change, we know that none of the currents through the resistors changed either.

Comment: exactly what i wanted thanks to your brain!! haha!!

Answer (score 1):

Since the circuit is fully symmetrical (left/right symmetry) the potential at C is exactly half the potential between A and B. This means that there is no current flowing across the point (from the "tip of the V" to the middle of the two resistors at point C), and you can break it without changing the underlying equations describing the current flow.

Comment: exactly what i wanted!!