Mirror symmetry in circuits
Consider this circuit below. The rectangular resistors have resistance 12 $\Omega$, and the circular water heaters have resistance 6 $\Omega$.
I am looking for a rigorous argument that explains why the voltage across heater $A$ is zero.

Though other questions concern this sort of electrical circuit question, see e.g. Why does the vertical resistor have no voltage across it?, in this case, the resistors have different resistance, so pure symmetry arguments are less intuitive. The explanations I've seen based on mirror symmetry are not clear enough to build an argument up from first principles, but this method seems to come up on physics olympiad questions with increasing levels of sophistication, but without the necessary clear explanations of the physics foundations.

This has been asked many times before - please consider using the search function.

See e.g. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/637648/174766, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/192588/174766, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/377555/174766

This question is similar to: Why does the vertical resistor have no voltage across it?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I did consider using the search function, this question is not the same as the others e.g. you have multiple sorts of resistors implying the paths across the system have distinct resistance. Also the questions is asking for rigor on mirror symmetry arguments, so its not just a homework question (this is a late stage question from a physics olympaid-like paper). I edited to explain how I need an argument from first principles.

I don't understand. Exactly what "first principles" argument are you looking for? Symmetry is a rigorous argument. You don't even need symmetry - the answer is obtainable from just Ohm's law. Neither requires the resistors in the different branches to be equal - just the equality of the two resistors in each branch is needed.

To elaborate, symmetry is mathematically rigorously formulated in terms of group theory.

Saying "symmetry is rigorous" isn't helpful when explaining this to a high school student. You have to use basic principles to justify the use of symmetry first, then use symmetry as a quick method later on once you accept and can explain why its used.

I do apologize but I still don't understand what "basic principles" you're talking about. Symmetry is the basic principle. It tells us that if we flip the circuit around, it is identical. So the potential at the center has to be halfway. Formulated as an equation, it is $V_2 - V = V - V_1$. The equality holds because the circuit remains the same when flipped. This is something I was taught in high school.

Remove heater A.
In terms of a vertical line through the centre the resistors and heater on the left side of that line are arranged in the same way as the resistors and heater on the right side of the line.
They are mirror images so one would expect that the currents through the components and the voltages across them are also mirror images.
Thus the potential of nodes on the vertical central line must be 84/2 = 42V.
Connecting heater A between nodes at the same potential means that the potential difference across heater A is zero and so is the current through it.

Is there a way it can be made more  rigorous, this point, so that it’s clearer why the symmetry leads to a lack of potential between the nodes?

@apg Would using Kirchhoff's current law and voltage law be rigorous enough?  What you have is a balanced Wheatstone bridge.

The question is essentially about how you would build the argument up from a first principles, it help as teaching aid for more advanced electrical circuit questions.
